# Laravel issue on calling belongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project about quizzes and their questions,
I don't know why but when i'm trying to get the quiz's questions i get
[this error](http://up419.siz.co.il/up3/jwyzeemm10ym.jpg)

This are my files and scripts:

Route web.php file:

```
Route::get('/admin/quizzes/{id}/questions', 'AdminQuizzesController@questions')->name('admin.quizzes.questions')
```

Model Quiz.php file:

```
class Quiz extends Model
{
    protected $dates = [ 'start_at', 'end_at', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'category_id', 'level_id', 'is_active', 'start_at', 'end_at'
    ];

    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question');
    }
}
```

Model Question.php file:

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'correct_answer', 'category_id', 'level_id'
    ];

    public function quiz(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Quiz');
    }
}
```

Controller AdminQuizzesController.php file:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Quiz;

class AdminQuizzesController extends Controller
{
    public function questions($id)
    {
        $quiz = Quiz::findOrFail($id);
        $questions = $quiz->questions;
        return view('admin.quizzes.questions.index', compact('quiz', 'questions'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u try running 'composer dump-autoload' in ur cmd

Comment: It's unrelated to the problem you're having, but the questions() relation should return hasMany(), not belongsToMany()

Comment: @MazinoSUkah Thanks this solved my problem. can you explain a bit more about the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer of @MazinoSUkah solved my problem.

just did 'composer dump-autoload' in my cmd

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK composer dump-autoload regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class inside your project or changed/renamed a class file. Hope it helps.